# Access method variable in jUnit test

Tags: java, junit

How can I use 2 variable from method below in jUnit test, but Eclipse tells me that I cannot access this variable. How can I make it accesible in any way? Or I need to define tests in other class?

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.*;

public class Sequence {

    public void MissingNumber() {  
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8};  
        int length = arr.length;  

        int indexes = 8;
        int values = 0;  

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {  
            indexes += i+1;  
            values += arr[i];  

            int result = indexes - values;  

            System.out.println("Indexes:" + indexes);
            System.out.println("Values:" + values);
            System.out.println("Missing number is: "+ result);  
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testCase1() {
        Assert.assertEquals("4", result); //need to use result
    }

    @Test
    public void testCase2() {
        Assert.assertEquals("10", values); //need to use values
    }
}
```

Comment: Write methods that return the values you want and test those.  You can't access variables from other methods or the results they printed out.  You need to break your code up into methods.

Comment: To expand on that a bit: You can't access local variables from other method in Java, full stop. JUnit test methods are completely normal methods that JUnit knows to call. They do not have any special rules (like being able to access local variables from another method).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea of unit testing is that you have a method that takes given parameters and should produce some expected output. Rewriting your program to make it work that way, for example:

```
public int missingNumber(int[] arr) {
    int length = arr.length;

    int indexes = 8;
    int values = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        indexes += i + 1;
        values += arr[i];
    }

    return indexes - values;
}

@Test
public void testResultFor_1_2_3_5_6_7_8() {
    int result = missingNumber(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8});
    Assert.assertEquals(4, result);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, it works great, but is there any way to access variable in jUnit directly? for example: I want to put all my jUnit teste to separate file and also do not return anything in my program, and want to check 3 variables in tests: indexes, values, result, I do not want to modify program for tests, I wnat tests to be separate. Is it possible?

Comment: The tests can (and should) be in a separate file. But you need to refactor your programs to work this way, having small functions taking parameters and return values. Decomposing bigger programs to smaller functional, reusable units is the recommended practice in programming

Comment: So, as I understood, better to split program to small functions that return values, and then test returned values?

Answer (score 2):

Try to really extract (and abstract) your logic into methods. Thus the methods will end up having arguments and results, making it easy to unit test each method (with differing arguments).

Comment: Arguments and results.